# How to convert DES key into String

Tags: java, encoding, cryptography, des

In have the following code for generating des key:

```
String password = "abcd1234";
DESKeySpec key = new DESKeySpec(password.getBytes());
//SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
System.out.println(key);
```

I want to convert this key into string and then back to key.

Is there any way to do this in Java.

Comment: The value in `DESKeySpec` would be same as `password` in the bytes format. Why do you want to provide and read the same value?

Comment: A password is **not** a key. If you have a password, you should derive a key from it using PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt or Argon2.

Comment: **Don't use DES nowadays.** It only provides 56 bit of security. AES would be a much better, because it's more secure with the lowest key size of 128 bit. There is also a practical limit on the maximum ciphertext size with DES. See [Security comparison of 3DES and AES](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/26179/45523).

Answer (score 0):

What you have is not a key:

```
String password = "abcd1234";
byte[] bytes = password.getBytes();
DESKeySpec key = new DESKeySpec(bytes);
System.out.println(new String(key.getKey()));
```

just generates a `KeySpec`. Now the derived class `SecretKeySpec` is derived from `SecretKey`, but `DESKeySpec` is not. A key specification is little more than the input material for a key.

As you can see it is easy to convert it to a `String` again.

---

Now lets really generate a key:

```
String password = "abcd1234";
byte[] bytes = password.getBytes();
DESKeySpec keySpec = new DESKeySpec(bytes);
SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
SecretKey key = keyFactory.generateSecret(keySpec);
System.out.println(new String(key.getEncoded()));
```

this will print `abcd1234` instead of `abbd1224`. This is because the key factory correctly sets the parity bits in the low part of each byte. As each byte is representing a character using most default character sets your string will differ. As the lowest bit value is erased it is impossible to revert to the original string (without guessing).

---

Notes:

- DES should not be used;
- Strings should not hold key information;
- the (default) platform character set generally not be used.